# Why can't I import directly from the index.ts of the root 'src' directory in a nested package

Tags: typescript, vite

As the title mostly describes, I'm having a hard time directly importing from a nested package (`core/assets`), whereas importing from index files (that live in the `src/` directory) from other packages that live outside of core work just fine.

The file structure I have resembles the following:

```
main
-- packages
---- core
------ assets
-------- src
---------- index.ts
---------- components
------------ loading
-------------- LoadingOverlay.tsx
-------------- CenteredLoadingIndicator.tsx
-------- package.json
-------- tsconfig.json
-- vite.config.ts
-- etc.
```

My `package.json` file looks like the following:

```
{
    "name": "@core/assets",
    "description": "Loading and image assets",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": {
        ...
    },
    "private": true,
    "main": "build/index.js",
    "types": "build/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "analyze": "npx analyze-trace trace || true",
        "trace": "tsc --generateTrace trace",
        "build": "tsc --build",
        "check": "yarn build",
        "test": "yarn build && vitest $*",
        "clean": "../../../go/clean",
        "disinfect": "../../../go/disinfect"
    },
    "exports": {
        ".": "./build/index.js",
        "./*": "./build/*"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        ...
    }
}
```

And the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "../../../tsconfig.build.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "build",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "composite": true,
        "include": [
                "src/*", "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

In the `index.ts` file in `core/assets`, I export a couple of components like so

```
export {default as CenteredLoadingIndicator} from './components/loading/LoadingOverlay'
export {default as LoadingOverlay} from './components/loading/LoadingOverlay'
```

However, when I try to import from other packages, as I would any other package, the project will build successfully, however, starting it results in a `vite dep-error`, pointing towards any one of the spots I'm trying to import `LoadingOverlay` or `CenteredLoadingIndicator`.

There are a few oddities I've noticed that have me perplexed.

1. If the `index.ts` file is moved **inside** of the `components/` folder, and all imports adjusted from `import ... from '@core/assets'` to `import ... from '@core/assets/components'`, it **will work**.
2. If I move the assets folder outside of the `core/` directory, and adjust all corresponding paths, it **will work**, telling me it is not an issue in the various `package.json` imports throughout the app.
3. If I change all imports from `import ... from '@core/assets'` to `import ... from '@core/assets/index'`, everything **will work** and no errors are thrown.
4. If I try this same procedure of exporting from an index file that lives in the `src/` directory of another nested package, the same error occurs.

I want to understand why this is, and if there is a way to fix it and maintain a cleaner import whether it's something in my `vite.config.ts` file or something I am not understanding about the way index files should export components.